# How to mix Select 2 Loading Remote Data with Initial Selections

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax

For select2, I wanna:

1. List some initial selections, so for small list, we can select it directly.
2. Search remote for long/more selections.

But, it seems I cannot provide both `ajax` and `data` parameter at same time.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

---

code snippet added

```
function installShopSelect2() {
    var url = "/ajax/brandEnterprise/findShops.mapi";
    "use strict";
    $('#shopid').select2({
        ajax: {
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            delay: 250,
            //async: false,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    keyword: params.term,
                    besId: selectedBes,
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
                // scrolling can be used
                params.page = params.page || 1;

                return {
                    results: data,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
            return markup;
        },
        //data: $.getJSON(url, {besId: selectedBes, keyword: ''}, function (data) {
        //    return {results: data};
        //}),
        placeholder: "--Please search--",
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        allowClear: true
    });
}
```

Comment: did you try setting allowClear: false ?

Comment: Nope, that didn't work for me either

Comment: Accessing a remote data in most cases is going to be fast enough that I don't see why you are trying to "prime the pump"  I copied and ran their sample on my box, connecting to their data source and got back data almost imediately

Comment: I've added the code snippet. The list is empty unless user typed at least two characters.  FIRST:   The requirement may be trivial for languages like English. But it is very bothering for languages like Chinese. User must use IME (Input Method Editor) to input two Chinese characters, which is more than two keystrokes.  If we are lucky, we may select item from initial list directly, especially for short list.  SECOND: Initial empty list may mislead user. They will growl, "Nothing, Nothing", ... and try to kill me.

Answer (score 3):

The way i solved this is setting the minimumInputLength=0, writing a custom ajax transporter that checks the length of the search term, when its equals to 0 i call the success callback with fixed default values, otherwise if greater than 0 i just do the ajax call and return the response.

Comment: Can you paste a code sample? This sounds like exactly what I need.